# Sublime Regex: Add digit to end of search group

Tags: regex, sublimetext3, regex-group

I want to add a digit to the end of a search group, but I can't figure out how to keep the digit from interfering with the group reference in the replacement pattern:

```
Text: Someword 8888
Pattern: ^(\w+\s\d+)
Replacement pattern: ???
Desired result: Someword 88881
```

`$11` looks for the eleventh search group, and results in an empty string

`$1\1` results in `Someword 8888Someword8888`

`$1\\1` results in `Someword 8888\1`

I know that this could be done in two separate find/replaces, but I want to know if there is a way this can be done in one.

Comment: Replace with `\11`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways to get your desired result.

You may use a POSIX like replacement backreference `\1` to insert Group 1 value and since there can be only 9 such backreferences, `\11` is parsed as backreference to Group 1 and a `1`.

Or, use `${1}1` where `${1}` is an unambiguous replacement backreference with `1` after it.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for explaining the difference between `\1`, `$1` and `${1}`, I've been looking for that explanation for a while.